# How does /etc/sudoers affect .ICEauthority?

Tags: sudo, authentication

I modified the `/etc/sudoers` file by adding this line:

```
me ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I can now run anything in `/home/me` as root without entering the password. When I reboot, however, I am not able to login as `me` ( both with and without activating autologin). I get this error:

```
could not update /home/me/.ICEauthority
```

Now, if I run `sudo chown me:me .ICEauthority`, this lets me login once. At the next reboot, the same issue occurs. I can, however, log in through `ssh`.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's likely nothing to do with the /etc/sudoers file *directly*, but rather a result of the particular applications that you chose to run using `sudo`: see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)